# Determine the force F acting on the particle at time $t=\frac{\pi}2$ to keep it moving along the given curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I understand how to find part (a).  It is the norm of the velocity when $t=2$, however I am clueless as to how to tackle (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Differentiate it twice to get the acceleration.  Then use the fact that force = mass times acceleration.